# Defining model in Camel-swagger

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, swagger

I am building RESTful Web services using Apache Camel (version 2.15.3), producing JSON output. Camel-swagger is used for API documentation.

There is a DTO which has a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` field. Since that object can be very ugly in JSON, I applied a custom Serializer for that field. It looks like this in the DTO:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ZonedDateTimeSerializer.class)
private ZonedDateTime created;
```

The ZonedDateTimeSerializer class is just creating a ZonedDateTimeVO class, which is my custom form of ZonedDateTime.

With this setup, swagger creates a model for my DTO with the ZonedDateTime property (type: `$ref ZonedDateTime`). It also creates the models for ZonedDateTime and its field objects. This is not valid, since the endpoints are not returning a ZonedDateTime (but my custom representation). I'd like to tell swagger to create a model for my custom ZonedDateTimeVO class.

I tried so far: annotating the `created` field in my DTO with `@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "ZonedDateTimeVO")` annotation and adding `@ApiModel` annotation to ZonedDateTimeVO class.
This way swagger creates a model for my DTO with property of ZonedDateTimeVO (type: $ref ZonedDateTimeVO), but it does not create a model for ZonedDateTimeVO itself. That is the problem actually, I cannot make swagger "scan" or "find" my custom type.

How should I do it?

Comment: Have you checked this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355872/how-to-set-apimodelproperty-datatype-to-string-for-swagger-documentation?

Comment: @Sergey I did not read it yet, thanks for pointing out. I don't think it is relevant for me though. I was able to use dataType="string" in another DTO.

Comment: If you are using jackson I would recommend using [the threeten module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310)