# How to set dataType to String for Swagger documentation

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using glassfish 4.1.1 and have integrated Swagger API documentation using the swagger 1.6.6 library.

I have a base class that looks something like this:

```
@ApiModel(value = "long")
public abstract class MyBaseClass {
    ...
   private long value;
   
  @JsonValue
   public long getValue() {
      return value;
   }       

   public long getMaxValue(){
        return 999999999;
   }
   public long getMinValue(){
        return 999999999;
   }  
}
```

Also I have classes that inherit this base class which look something like this:

```
  public class MyClass extends MyBaseClass {
    ......
     public MyClass(long value) {
         ....
     }
     public static MyClass Empty = new MyClass();
  }
```

I expect the result to look like this:

```
{
 MyClass: "String"
}
```

but I get the following result:

```
 "MyClass": {
    "minValue": 0,
    "maxValue": 0,
    "empty": true
  }
```

I have tried putting the @ApiModelProperty annotation on the field as well as the method, and in both cases the required field is respected, but the dataType field is ignored. I have also tried using "String", "string", and "java.lang.String" for the dataType but none of those have worked.
I read a similar post [How to set @ApiModelProperty dataType to String for Swagger documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355872/how-to-set-apimodelproperty-datatype-to-string-for-swagger-documentation) but it uses springfox and (Swagger 3.0). I am using swagger 1.6.6

Please tell me where which property can be configured to get the required result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be useful to someone. In the end, in the class in which I use this type I put the @ApiModelProperty(dataType="string") anatomy everywhere,

```
MyApiClass{

  @ApiModelProperty(dataType="string")
  public MyClass var;

}
```

the result began to look as it should:

```
{
 MyClass: "String"
}
```

but this is not quite what I needed. I was looking for a solution where I don't have to put @ApiModelProperty(dataType="string") everywhere when using this type.